# TEST REACT AgGRID component using JEST and React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a to test AG GRID COMPONENT Using this :

```
function GridView() {
  // OTHER CODE HERE ...
return (
<div className="mt-3 ag-theme-sg-bootstrap" data-testid="adjustment-grid">
      <AgGridReact<IAdjustment>
        className="ag-theme-sg-bootstrap"
        data-testid="ag-grid-react-root"
        pagination={true}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        getRowId={(data) => data.data.indicator}
        paginationPageSize={10}
        domLayout="autoHeight"
        gridOptions={gridOptions}
        animateRows={true}
        rowSelection="single"
        defaultColDef={{ filter: true, floatingFilter: true, sortable: true }}
        rowModelType="serverSide"
      />
)
}
```

In GridView.test.tsx,

```
test('fetches adjustments data and displays it in the grid on grid ready', async () => {
    waitFor(() => {
      render(<GridView/>);
      const adjustmentGridElement = screen.getByTestId('adjustment-grid');
      console.log(adjustmentGridElement)
}) 
})
```

it retrun

```
<div style="height: 100%;"></div>
```

Without AG GRID

Getting AG GRID RENDER DOM VALUES ON JEST